# Why there is a huge difference between the basicity of urea and guanidine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, molecular-structure

The two molecules have very similar structures, but urea has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ of $13.9,$ while guanidine have a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ of $0.4.$ If guanidine cation can be stabilized by resonance, then why can't urea cation do so?

Comment: Probably this can be the answer- all three canonical forms of guanidine are equivalent, while of urea aren't.

Comment: For the same reason that ammonia is a much stronger base than water, even though their structures are very similar in the same sense.

Answer (score 2):

Urea and guanidine are structurally similar except that the carbonyl oxygen of urea has been replaced by an imine $\ce{NH}$ in guanidine. When it come to protonation, carbonyl oxygen of urea is always protonated over its 2 $\ce{NH2}$ groups (Ref.1 and 2). In guanidine, it is the imine $\ce{NH}$ protonated first. This preference in guanidine is not because a lone pair of $\mathrm{sp^2}$ nitrogen is more basic than that of $\mathrm{sp^3}$ nitrogen (actually it is other way around), but the lone pair of $\mathrm{sp^2}$ nitrogen is the most available pair for protonation over those of two $\mathrm{sp^2}$ nitrogens (lone pairs of two $\mathrm{sp^2}$ nitrogen atoms are contributing to resonance stabilization at the time). However, when protonated, guanidinium ion was highly stabilized by resonance as depicted in the diagram:

[image: Guanidine and Urea]

Thus, basically, it  comes down to protonation ability of oxygen versus nitrogen. Oxygen is more electronegative than that of nitrogen, thus like to retain its lone pare better than nitrogen (*cf.* basicity of water and ammonia). Therefore, in that sense alone, guanidine is a better base than urea.

References:

1. Nanping Wen, Murray H. Brooker, “Urea protonation: Raman and theoretical study,” *J. Phys. Chem.* **1993**, *97(33)*, 8608-8616 (https://doi.org/10.1021/j100135a013).
2. B. Valentine, T. E. St. Amour, D. Fiat, “A $\ce{^{17}O}$ NMR study of the protonation of urea,” *Organic Magnetic Resonance* **1984**, *22(11)*, 697-700 (https://doi.org/10.1002/mrc.1270221105).